# Mathematica: Overriding `Listable` property of `Plus`

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to define a symbol `pt` to hold a point (and eventually cache some data related to that point):

```
pt::"usage" = "pt[{x,y}] represents a point at {x,y}";
```

I would like to be able to use such `pt` objects as points in as many ways as possible, an particularly, I would like to be able to write

```
{a0,a1}+pt[{b0,b1}]
```

and have it return `pt[{a0+b0,a1+b1}]` rather than `{a0+pt[{b0,b1}],a1+pt[{b0,b1}]}`.
My original idea was to use:

```
pt /: Plus[pt[p0_], p1 : {_, _}] = pt[p0 + p1];
```

But this doesn't work (because `Plus` is `Listable`?). Is there a way to do this without unprotecting `Plus`?

**Update:**
As Leonid points out, this is not possible without globally or locally hacking `Plus`, since the `Listable` attribute is considered before any *values. This is actually described very precisely in the [evaluation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html).

Comment: You could do `InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["+"], MyPlus];` and then have MyPlus defer to Plus for everything except Point

Comment: @Yaroslaw. Thanks for pointing out how to actually do this with `Notation`. I figured there was a way, but also decided to not go this direction because it seems to always come back and bite you as unwanted side effects...

Comment: yeah, behavior caused by changing built-in behavior is hard to debug. When I need new behavior I define my own version in lowercase. So for instance I have "table", "sum" and "intersection" that are customized versions of Table/Sum/Intersection

Comment: Yup. In this case, it is not even that painful: I just have to do `pt[{a0,a1}]+pt[{b0,b1}]` and then define an uprule to get `Plus` working. Still, I wanted to see if anybody knew of a nicer way.

Comment: I wonder what is the goal of your pt[] symbol. Risking a side question - Why do you use it (instead of just a list)? What data are you planning to cache, and how?

Comment: @j0ker: I'm caching the results of some very expensive intermediate function evaluations as `pt[{x,y},cache]`. I cannot use global memoization since (a) the full context is a bit too complex and (b) I need the data to fall out of scope on a point by point basis. It has proven to be very nice to work with for everything else, e.g. `F[pt[{x_,y_},{c1_,c2_,____}]:=...`, so I just wondered if there was a way around this little annoyance.

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov what customizations have you made to Sum, Table and Intersection?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `table`/`sum` to work like `Table`, but with index variable specified as first argument, more readable with nested sums, `intersection` to use with lists when order needs to be preserved -- http://yaroslavvb.com/mma/Bulatov/common.m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica's evaluator seems not flexible enough to do this easily. UpValues for pt indeed are applied before DownValues for Plus, but threading over lists due to Listability happens even before that. In this particular case, the following might work for you:

```
eval = Function[code,Block[{Plus = Plus, attr = DeleteCases[Attributes[Plus], Listable]},
SetAttributes[Plus, attr]; code], HoldAll]
```

To use it, wrap it around a piece of code where you want your rule for pt to apply, e.g.:

```
eval[{a0, a1} + pt[{b0, b1}]]
```

You can use $Pre as `$Pre = eval` to avoid typing eval every time, although generally I would not recommend this. Blocking Plus is a softer way of disabling some or all of its Attributes temporarily. The advantage w.r.t. clearing and setting attributes without Block is that you can not end up in a global state with Listable attribute permanently disabled, even if exception is thrown or the computation is Abort-ed.

Since Listable attribute directly affects evaluation rather than pattern-matching (the latter may of course be affected indirectly if some pattern has to match the result of Plus threaded over a list), this should be ok in most cases. In theory, it may still lead to some unwanted effects in some cases, particularly where pattern-matching is involved. But in practice, it might be good enough. A cleaner but more complex solution would be to create a custom evaluator tailored to your needs.

Comment: +1 for confirming my suspicions about the evaluation order with regard to Listable. Was going to ask if you knew of the documentation for this, but when you know what to look for it is actually stated very clearly at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html. Will add the link to my question and checkmark you for answering my question in the negative :) As for my solution, wrapping bare points in `pt` will be cleaner for my uses.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a bit wasteful, but it works: The idea is to simply watch for cases where the `Listable` attribute of `Plus` has put the same `pt` into all elements of a list (i.e. a raw point) -- and then pull it back out. First, define a function for adding pt objects:

```
SetAttributes[ptPlus, {Orderless}]
ptPlus[pt[pa : {_, _}], pt[pb : {_, _}], r___] := 
  ptPlus[pt[pa + pb], r];
ptPlus[p_pt] := p;
```

Then we make sure that any `Plus` which involves a `pt` is mapped to `ptPlus` (an associate the rule with pt).

```
Plus[h___, a_pt, t___] ^:= ptPlus[h, a, t];
```

The above rules means that: `{x0,y0}+pt[{x1,y1}]` will be expanded from `{x0+pt[{x1,y1}],y0+pt[{x1,y1}]}` to `{ptPlus[x0,pt[{x1,y1}]],ptPlus[y0,pt[{x1,y1}]]}`. Now we just make a rule to transform this to `pt[{x0,y0}]+pt[{x1,y1}]` (note the deferred condition which checks that the `pt`s are equal):

```
{ptPlus[x__], ptPlus[y__]} ^:= Module[{
    ptCases = Cases[{{x}, {y}}, _pt, {2}]},
  ptCases[[1]] + pt[Plus @@@ DeleteCases[{{x}, {y}}, _pt, {2}]] 
    /; Equal @@ ptCases]
```

A more opaque, but slightly more careful version which is easier to generalize to higher dimensions:

```
ptPlus /: p : {_ptPlus, _ptPlus} := Module[{ptCases, rest,
   lp = ReleaseHold@Apply[List, Hold[p], {2}]},
  ptCases = Cases[lp, _pt, {2}];
  rest = Plus @@@ DeleteCases[lp, _pt, {2}];
  ptCases[[1]] + pt[rest] /; And[Equal @@ ptCases, VectorQ@rest]]
```

This whole approach will of course lead to horribly subtle bugs when  `{a+pt[{0,0}],a+pt[{0,b}]} /. {a -> pt[{0,0}]}` evaluates to `pt[{0,0}]` when `c==0` and `{pt[{0,0}],pt[{0,c}]}` otherwise...

HTH -- said the guy to himself...